# CSS target Safari 8 only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

While I was doing some optimizations on my web, I ran into some trouble with Safari.

I have some CSS commands, which are broken on Safari 8 (maybe unsupported?), Safari 9 and all other browsers are OK.

I would like to fix the code for safari 8, without breaking and rebuilding my code using different (and much more complicated) structure to achieve the same output.

So:
Is here a way to target !ONLY! safari version 8?

Targeting could be any-

- as comment in html, like old comments for "if IE7"
- as in CSS somehow (but -webkit targets all webkit browsers, not only safari)
- as in javascript/jquery

So, any sugggestions, please?

Comment: Sounds like a lost cause, to be honest. A better idea would be to target the issue and work out why Safari doesn't like it, and offer a fallback for browsers that don't support a feature (if that's the problem).

Comment: it is actually the only CSS command `transform: translate(0,50%);` ... on all common browsers (firefox, ie11+, opera, chrome) works perfectly. On safari 7 and below, my page does not work at all, it seems it has a problem loading handling my JS and CSS files, but its ok... SAFARI 8 has almost everything fine, except this transform, which I use for making some positioning much more simple, and then SAFARI 9, where everything works fine. Even if only very low % of people uses apple here, I'd like to add Safari8 support, but it is the only browser, which has a problem with this command... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of different ways you can solve the problem.  If you want to inject a stylesheet, you may use the code below:

```
var ua='Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.75.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.3 Safari/7046A194A';
var verRe = /Version\/(\d+)/;
var version = ua.match(verRe);
var safari = ua.indexOf("Safari");

if (safari !== -1) {
    if (version[1] <= 8) {
        addStyleTag("safari8.css");
    }
}

function addStyleTag(url) {
    var link,head;
    head = document.querySelector("head");
    link = document.createElement("link");
    link.setAttribute("href",url);
    link.setAttribute("type","text/css");
    link.setAttribute("rel","stylesheet");
    head.appendChild(link);
}
```

If it was my page, I would write the code to degrade gracefully on Safari.

Comment: This seems to be triggering and adding the CSS to all browsers. Does it work out of the box or am I missing something?

Comment: It should be working 'out-of-the-box', you may want to check the **ua** string.  In a production environment, **ua** on the fourth line would be replaced with **navigator.userAgent**.

Answer (score 1):

You could use browser detection and add or not add (depending on the browser) a class to the `body` (e.g. `<body class="is-safari-8">`). In your CSS you could set specific rules only applying to `.is-safari-8` and its descendants.

The browser detection itself can be done either on the server or client side. While server side is probably preferable I'm assuming you intend to do it client side.
For this you can either use a library (you should find several with a quick google search but it might be overkill since you are looking for just one specific case) or write your own script to check the user agent.

Here is a helpful source that should get you started:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Navigator

On a sidenote:
The user agent can be faked (but that probably won't be an issue here).

More importantly: you might want to look up https://modernizr.com/. It's a feature detection script. It might allow you to solve your problem in a more flexible way.